# Email contents of a row created mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a created a table that has been generated with php. One of the columns contains a submit button.  I would like it for the submit button email the contents of that row.  So for example, when the button is hit, column 2 of that row would be the sender's email address, column 3 would be the subject, and column 4 would be the body of the email.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is my code so far:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="" >

<div id='displaytodo'>

<?php 

//**********************************************
//*
//*  Connect to MySQL and Database
//*
//**********************************************

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root', 'EmilDB');

if (!$db)
{
    print "<h1>Unable to Connect to MySQL</h1>";
}


//**********************************************
//*
//*  SELECT from table and display Results
//*
//**********************************************

// CREATES SQL STATEMENT
$sql_statement  = "SELECT Date, Topic, subject, send_to, body, status     

";
$sql_statement .= "FROM ToDo ";
$sql_statement .= "ORDER BY DATE ";
//$sql_statement .= "WHERE state = 'CA' ";
//$sql_statement .= "ORDER BY lastname, firstname ";

// CREATES VARIABLE THAT COMBINES CONNECT STATEMENT AND SQL STATEMENT
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_statement);

// SETS COUNTER FOR THE WHILE STATEMENT THAT IS COMING UP
$outputDisplay = "";
$myrowcount = 0;

// IF THERE IS AN ERROR MESSAGE
if (!$result) {
    $outputDisplay .= "<p style='color: red;'>MySQL No:     
    ".mysqli_errno($db)."<br>";
    $outputDisplay .= "MySQL Error: ".mysqli_error($db)."<br>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<br>SQL: ".$sql_statement."<br>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<br>MySQL Affected Rows: 
      ".mysqli_affected_rows($db)."</p>";
 //print $outputDisplay;


  }else {

//// CREATES HEADER
    $outputDisplay  = "<h3>To Do</h3>";
//// CREATES TABLE
    $outputDisplay .= '<table border=1 style="color: black;">';
//// CREATES TABLE FIRST ROW
    $outputDisplay .= '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Topic</th><th>Subject</th>        
      <th>Send To</th><th>Body</th><th>Status</th><th>Email</th></tr>';

/// DETERMINE HOW MANY ROWS THERE ARE IN TABLE, TO BE USED IN FOR LOOP
$numresults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

/// FOR LOOP
for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++)
{
    if (!($i % 2) == 0)
    {
         $outputDisplay .= "<tr style=\"background-color: #F5DEB3;\">";
    } else {
         $outputDisplay .= "<tr style=\"background-color: white;\">";
    }

    $myrowcount++;

// CREATES TABLE
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $id  = $row['ToDo_int'];
    $date  = $row['Date'];
    $topic  = $row['Topic'];
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $send_to = $row['send_to'];
    $body = $row['body'];

    $email = '<input type="submit" name= "email" value="Email">';




    $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$date."</td>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$topic."</td>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$subject."</td>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$send_to."</td>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$body."</td>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$status."</td>";
    $outputDisplay .= "<td>".$email."</td>";

    $outputDisplay .= "</tr>";



}
/// END TAG FOR TABLE

$outputDisplay .= "</table>";


        /// Email
//if(isset($_POST['$id'])){
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ 
    echo("works");

    mail('infot@gmail.com', 'subject', 'body');
}


}



?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: You're fetching the results. Why not put the results into a string and then put that string in the email?

Comment: Hello,  How do I put the corresponding row into a string? i'm not sure how to code that the button I submit, corresponds to the same row.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using a ref mailto workaround.  This is the line that I changed:

$email = 'Email';

Comment: I meant to this $email = '<a href="mailto:' .$send_to .'?subject=' .$subject . '&body=' . $body . '">Email</a>';